# Number of girls in a class

Tags: combinatorics

There are some boys and girls in a class. Every boy is friends with exactly three girls, and every girl is friends with exactly three boys. If there are 13 boys in the class, how many girls are there? (Assume that friendship is mutual, i.e. if A is friend of B then B is also friend of A.)

Comment: Welcome to Math StackExchange! We generally encourage people to describe what they have tried so that we can help better! Did you try converting the problem into one in graph theory?

Comment: No,I didn't try converting the problem into graph theory.

Answer (score 1):

Each of the $13$ boys has $3$ friends. So in total there are $39$ friendships in the class.

Now suppose, we have $x$ girls in the class, which also have $3$ friends each. Then the total number of friendships is $3\cdot x$.

And $3 \cdot x = 39 \implies x=13$. So there are $13$ girls in the class.